# How to Access a Dynamic struct from an external function C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic, data-structures, dev-c++

I'm trying to make a very simple text-based game and I encountered an error when I tried to access a dynamic struct from an external function. I initialized all variables and structs in my header file and declared a dynamic alloc in the main function. But still I got errors. Am I missing something? This is my code.

==================main function "new.cpp"====================

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "game.h"
using namespace std;

difficulty _df_1;
player* player_1 = new player[3];
int main()
    {
        //initialize player stats
        player_1->hp = 100;
        player_1->life = 3;
        player_1->mana = 50;
        player_1->player_id = 1;
        player_1->level = 1;
        player_1->player_name= "emmet";
        //..end
        int turn=1;
        cout << "What is your name? <<<";
        getline(cin,player_1->player_name,'\n');
        cout << "Choose a difficulty level: [0]Easy [1]Normal [2]Godlike" << endl;
        int ch;
        cin >> ch;
        switch(ch)
            {
                case 0:
                    cout << "Scardy Cat chose EASY." << endl;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cout << "A really nice way to start. NORMAL" << endl;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "Overly Manly Man is playing GODLIKE." << endl;
                    break;
                default:        cout << "I wonder how you can play this game if you can even read simple instructions."<< endl;return 0; break; 
            }
        while(turn == 1)
            {
                char ch;
                cout << "What do you want to do now? \n <<<<"; 
                cin >> ch;
                cin.ignore(5,'\n');
                switch(ch)
                    {
                        case 'a': case 'A':
                            player_stat();
                            break;
                        case 'v': case 'V':
                            cheat_menu();
                            break;
                        case 'x': case 'X':
                            return 0;
                            break;
                        case '`':

                            break;
                        default:    cout << "We were unable to process your request. Please try again" << endl; break;
                    }
            }
        delete player_1;
        return 0;
    }


void cheat_menu()
    {
        cout << "CHEATERS WILL ROT IN THE DEEPEST DEPTHS OF TARTARUS." << endl;
        cout << "Enter Code:" << endl;
        string cheat;
        getline(cin,cheat,'\n');
            if(cheat == "poo")
                {
                    system("sleep 3");
                    cout << "Cheat Activated.." << endl;
                    player_1->hp += 1000;
                    player_1->level += 10;
                    player_1->mana += 1000;
                    player_stat();
                }
            else
                {
                    cout << "Wrong cheat code.." << endl;
                }
        //system("sleep 3");
        //system("clear");
    }
```

==================end main function==============

=======external func "player_stat.cpp"===========

```
#include <iostream>
#include "game.h"
using namespace std;
void player_stat()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << player_1->player_name  << endl
        << "Hp: " << player_1->hp << endl
        << "Life: " << player_1->life << "\t Mana: " << player_1->mana << endl
        << "Level: " << player_1->level << "\t XP: " << player_1->xp
        << endl;
        //system("sleep 3");
        //system("clear");
}
```

==================end external func==============

==========header file "game.h"===================

```
#ifndef _GAME_
#define _GAME_

#include "player_stat.cpp"
using namespace std;

//function prototypes...
void player_stat();
void cheat_menu();


//structs for player and NPC
struct player
    {
        string player_name;
        int life;
        double atk;
        double hp;
        double mana;
        int player_id;
        int level;
        long int xp;
        string weapon_name;
        double weapon_damage;
    };
enum difficulty {EASY,NORMAL,GODLIKE};

#endif
```

===========end header file=======================

These are the errors I got. Please don't mind the other left out functions in int main(). :P

```
In file included from game.h:4
from new.cpp
in function `void player_stat()':
`player_1' undeclared (first use in this function)
(Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
At global scope:
`player*player_1' used prior to declaration
```

Comment: You create three `player` objects with `new player[3]`, then you use the pointer to access only the first one. If you only want one player, declare it as a normal variable, no need to allocate on heap.

Comment: @n.m. I had to un-link-to-[png-screencap](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lg6l9.png) it.

Comment: i could not dynamically alter struct members if i dont do that. new player[3]. i just did that to sigify that i only wanted maximum of 3 players in the game cuz i was planning on adding some socket functions to it. multiplayer that kind of stuff.

Comment: If you want multiple players, then I recommend [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. Or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you want a fixed number of players.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the
[faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You'll get a badge (c:

Comment: Thanks Peter Wood. :) I hope i'm not breaking any rules or guidelines in the faq  :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare the variable using the `extern` storage specifier:

```
extern player* player_1;
```

This tells the compiler that the `player_1` variable is defined somewhere else, and the linker will resolve it later.

---

Also as I noted you actually allocate *three* player objects. If you only need one then don't allocate three:

```
player* player_1 = new player;
```

However, that's not needed either, declaring a normal non-pointer variable will work just as fine:

```
player player_1;
```

Then in the other files you use `extern` to tell the compiler that the variable is defined somewhere else:

```
extern player player_1;
```

Comment: i understand that declaring it as dynamic is not needed. however..in the early stages when i coded this.. the value of the struct members doesn't seem to change. you might encountered the cheat_menu() func in main().. that was the purpose of that func. to test whether the structs will change based on the player activities.  so i needed to declare it as dynamic so that the values will change while in-game. try removing that allocation part. you'll notice that the cheat wont work.. thanks anyways..i'll try and consider your advice :)

Comment: @EmmetCooper I still don't see any reason to allocate it dynamically. Doing e.g. `player_1.hp += 1000;` is no different from doing `player_1->hp += 1000;`. The problem might have been that you passed the object around in arguments as _copies_ instead of e.g. by reference.

Comment: oh.. I see now.. i tried to make a simple program to test what you said.. and you were right.. Thanks :).. I'll remove the allocation..maybe it'll make my work easier..after all i'm just fairly new to c++ :p

Answer (score 0):

add

> extern player* player_1;

to game.h

this will make the player_1 variable available across all the modules.

also remove

> #include "player_stat.cpp"

you are not supposed to include any cpp  files in the header files

Comment: Sure.. I'll try it.. :).. Thanks for the super fast reply. :)